# UnsatisfiedLinkError problem

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, runtime-error

I'm developing an Android application that uses JNI.

The command `javah -jni com.company.tests.MainRenderer` gave me this output:

```
/*
 * Class:     com_company_tests_MainRenderer
 * Method:    nativeInit
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_company_tests_MainRenderer_nativeInit
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

/*
 * Class:     com_company_tests_MainRenderer
 * Method:    nativeRender
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_company_tests_MainRenderer_nativeRender
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);
```

The command `nm -Ca libRotateJNI.so` gave me this output:

```
00001c25 T Java_com_company_tests_MainRenderer_nativeInit(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*)
00001c29 T Java_com_company_tests_MainRenderer_nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*)
```

This is how are defined these functions:

```
void Java_com_company_tests_MainRenderer_nativeInit( JNIEnv*  env, jobject thiz )
{
    // ...
}

void Java_com_company_tests_MainRenderer_nativeRender( JNIEnv*  env, jobject thiz )
{
    // ...
}
```

And running it with this message:

```
WARN/dalvikvm(639): No implementation found for native Lcom/company/tests/MainRenderer;.nativeInit ()V
```

I'm sure library is loaded. Do you know how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you compiled your native methods with a C++ compiler, and didn't give them `extern "C"` linkage. The `-C` option you're providing to `nm` demangles the C++ names, but in reality, the symbols have names different from what the JVM is looking for because the code was compiled with C++ linkage. Enclose your C++ code in an `extern "C"` block and this should clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your MainRenderer is and what native library you are hitting but my c file functions always look something like this:

```
void Java_com_ndkfoo_NDKFooActivity_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {
```

The method/class I am calling is NDKFooActivity and its invoking a native Function...